# How to print all line numbers in the source file associated with the flow of a program in GDB

Tags: c++, debugging, gdb

is there a way to print(or dump to a separate file) all corresponding line numbers related to a C++ program in GDB

eg: source.cpp

```
#include <stdio.h> // line #1
int main()
{
    int i = 2;
    if(i == 1)
    {
        printf("i=1\n");
    }
    else if(i == 2)
    {
        printf("i=2\n");
    }
    else
    {
        printf("i=another\n");
    }
    return 0; // line #17
}
```

expected output : (it is better to dump the output to a file)

source.cpp : 2

source.cpp : 4

source.cpp : 5

source.cpp : 9

source.cpp : 11

source.cpp : 17

Comment: What you really want is to get where a function stepped afterwards?

Comment: i need to get file lines where the line 'highlighter' is goes, with 'n' command.(from a breakpoint to end of the program)

Comment: For what do you need that? You could maybe script that. with something like `expect`

Comment: When debugging a program with thousands of lines,I've used two test cases to compare the flows that execute them. if i can use something that i've asked then my analysis will be easier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess, you are looking for a something like `gcov` tool. Anyway, it's about code coverage, and not about interactive debugging. `gdb` also can do something like that, but `gcov` is specialized for this kind of analysis.

```
gcc code.cpp -fprofile-arcs -ftest-coverage
./a.out
gcov code.cpp
```

And in `code.cpp.gcov` you will get:

```
    -:    0:Source:code.cpp
    -:    0:Graph:code.gcno
    -:    0:Data:code.gcda
    -:    0:Runs:1
    -:    0:Programs:1
    -:    1:#include <stdio.h> // line #1
    1:    2:int main()
    -:    3:{
    1:    4:    int i = 2;
    1:    5:    if(i == 1)
    -:    6:    {
#####:    7:        printf("i=1\n");
    -:    8:    }
    1:    9:    else if(i == 2)
    -:   10:    {
    1:   11:        printf("i=2\n");
    -:   12:    }
    -:   13:    else
    -:   14:    {
#####:   15:        printf("i=another\n");
    -:   16:    }
    1:   17:    return 0; // line #17
    -:   18:}
```